# Internet Explorer not closing when debugging stops

Tags: c#, wpf, internet-explorer, xbap

I have an XBAP WPF application. Up until a few days ago, whenever I would stop debugging, internet explorer would realize that debugging had stopped and would close automatically. But for some reason when I stop debugging or the application errors and terminates Internet Explorer stays open. The frame clears out and is just white, not showing anything from my application, but the tab stays open.

I wish I could be more specific, or had any relevant code to show, but I don't know what could be causing it. Any clues as to what could be causing this? My best guess is there's something that's not getting disposed properly in my application that's not telling IE that the application has terminated, but since it happens after the debugger has already stopped, it's hard to track down.

Comment: well what has changed in your app in the last few days ?

Comment: I don't know of any changes that were made that would affect this, which is mostly because I don't know what could cause this. We haven't made any major changes to the app, just our typical work on it.

Comment: well *assuming you are using source control or something along those lines* I would suggest you get a previous version from like last week were you can guarantee it was working as expected. If that works then you can keep getting newer versions until it stops working and you will have your answer. Otherwise then it might be an issue in a newer version of ie or something similiar

Comment: okay, i got latest from source control on a different workspace, and i'm not experiencing the issue. it must be something weird going on with my user files (`.suo`, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got latest on my solution and a different workspace, and didn't experience this issue, so that led me to believe it was a user file causing the issue.

I closed the solution, deleted the solution's `MySolution.<version>.suo` file and reopened the solution and IE closes properly when debugging stops now.